# Rails or CSS replacing table cell content if certain string?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, if-statement, html-table

I have the following HTML table code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th class="hide-on-phones">Destination</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11 Mar. 2012 -  16:37</td>
    <td>0778593789</td>
    <td class="hide-on-phones">08456783850</td>
    <td>00:03:10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The content is populated from the Rails application database, the destination field is called destination in the database.

On the Rails side of things, the content is pulled from my Calls model which is populated by a rake task. The rake task screen scrapes our providers website for the call log.

Ideally, I would like to replace the destination content with a company name (without making database relationships etc). It's only for this page and the Rails application is tiny and simple.

I imagine either a CSS rule to replace the number with an image or a Rails statement to filter the number and if it matches a set value then replace with a phrase (company name).

Is there an easy way to do this that I have overlooked?

**UPDATE**

When using the following suggested code I get an error. I don't think the when statement can start with a zero.

```
module CallsHelper
  def format_destination(destination_number)
    case destination_number
    when 08456742850
      image_tag "number_1234.jpg"
    when 5678
      image_tag "number_5678.jpg"
    else
      image_tag "default_number.jpg"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `08456742850` is a malformed octal number. Is `destination_number` actually a number or is it a string? If a string (which I assume), you also want strings in the `when`. And you might want to use a hash instead of a `case` switch if that gets bigger than four or five entries. It's simply less code.

Comment: The destination_number is a string, and sample code or tutorials you can point me in the direction of?

Comment: When you're trying to match strings, use `when "08456742850"`. That level of Ruby is probably best covered in intro tutorials; I'm afraid I am not up-to-date where the good ones are these days. pragprog.com has good material, but afaicr not for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a helper method to convert your destination to the value you want to display?
I'm assuming that you have a distinct set of destinations that wont change, which will allow you to hard-code them in your application without needing to store them in the DB for modification later through the application?

Something like this?

```
def format_destination(destination_number)
  case destination_number
  when 1234
    image_tag "number_1234.jpg"
  when 5678
    image_tag "number_5678.jpg"
  else
    image_tag "default_number.jpg"
  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking about that but got confused! Would I then just call <%= call.format_destination %> in my view?

Comment: In your view you'd then just use `<td class="hide-on-phones"><%= format_destination 08456783850 %></td>` although if it's that tightly tied to the images you're using, why not just put the image_tags in yourself into the view in the first place?

Comment: It's not going to be images replacing them if I can help it, I want to replace specific numbers with specific company names. Would the following work? <%= format_destination call.destination %>

Comment: Yes, assuming you have an object called `call` with a method `destination` providing the value you want to pass into the `format_destination` helper.